# PointCloudLibrary crash on display

Tags: c++

I am working on PCL and the code crashes when I follow the tutorial. The code below works

```
PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>::Ptr pointCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Simple Cloud Viewer");
viewer.showCloud(pointCloud);
while (!viewer.wasStopped())
    {
    }
```

But this does not work http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php I think it might be because of ConstPtr but I do not know how to change Ptr to ConstPtr.

```
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer;
viewer = rgbVis(pointCloud);

while (!viewer->wasStopped())
{
    viewer->spinOnce(100);
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(100000));
}
```

With function definition below.

```
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> rgbVis(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr cloud)
{
    // --------------------------------------------
    // -----Open 3D viewer and add point cloud-----
    // --------------------------------------------
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("3D Viewer"));
    viewer->setBackgroundColor(0, 0, 0);
    pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> rgb(cloud);
    viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>(cloud, rgb, "sample cloud");
    viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 3, "sample cloud");
    viewer->addCoordinateSystem(1.0);
    viewer->initCameraParameters();
    return (viewer);
}
```

It crashes at this line `viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>(cloud, rgb, "sample cloud");`

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUQEv.png)

"acrt_first_block == header"

Comment: Please provide error messages to help us find out what caused the crash.

Comment: Hi thanks ! I have edited the post to include the error message. I am not allowed to post pictures however. But it basically says "acrt_first_block == header"

Comment: Anyone any comments ?